# How to add class style with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add extra class to nav bar using JS and probably I am doing something wrong.

So I am adding class via classList.add('class') 
it is showing on inspect that class included but it is not working. 
Please see code below

html

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md py-0 fixed-top">
```

css

```
.navbar .scrolled { background: black;}
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("#mainNavbar").classList.add("scrolled");
console.log(document.querySelector("#mainNavbar").classList);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-to-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I think css should be

```
.navbar.scrolled { background: black;}
```

Same element classes should be without any space like. **.navbar.scrolled**

With space it targets child elements.